# How to link sql sub queries together?

Tags: sql, join

is it possible to link the following sub query (see below.) The first three sub queries work fine however  I'm struggling to see how to do the rest any guidance would be great cheers.

Ps. apologies for the long code

```
SELECT c.[Status],
       c.CompanyId,
       c.Name,


       (SELECT count(DISTINCT usr.UserID)
        FROM   [ondemand.10cms.com].Security.[user] usr
               INNER JOIN [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company
                 ON usr.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
        WHERE usr.CompanyID = c.CompanyID) AS TotalUsers,

       (SELECT sum (CASE WHEN usr.Status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        FROM   [ondemand.10cms.com].Security.[user] usr
        INNER JOIN [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company
        ON usr.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
        WHERE usr.CompanyID = c.CompanyID) AS ActiveUsers,

       (SELECT sum (CASE WHEN usr.Status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        FROM   [ondemand.10cms.com].Security.[User] usr
       INNER JOIN [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company
ON usr.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID WHERE usr.CompanyID = c.CompanyID) AS SuspendedUsers,

    (Select COUNT (distinct usrs.id)
    From [ondemand.10cms.com].Security.UserSession usrs
 inner join [ondemand.10cms.com].Security.[user] usr on usrs.UserID=usr.UserID
    ) as TotalLogin,


    (Select 
    COUNT( MerchandisingModule.Name)
    From [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.Template 
    inner join [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.MerchandisingModule  on Template.TemplateID= MerchandisingModule.TemplateId
    )as CurrentModules,

    (Select 
    count(MerchandisingModule.CreatedDate)
    from [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.MerchandisingModule 
    inner join [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.Template  on Template.TemplateID= MerchandisingModule.TemplateId
    )as ModulesCreated,

 (Select 
    count(mm.UpdatedDate)
    from [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.MerchandisingModule mm
    inner join [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.Template  on Template.TemplateID= mm.TemplateId
 )as ModulesUpdated,


    (Select 
    COUNT(MA.MerchandisingAreaID)
    from [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.MerchandisingArea MA
    inner join [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.Project  on Project.ProjectID= MA.ProjectID
    ) as Currentareas,


    (Select 
    COUNT (MA.name)
    from [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.MerchandisingArea MA
    inner join [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.Project  on Project.ProjectID= MA.ProjectID
    ) as AreasCreated,



    (select 
    COUNT (MerchandisingArea.UpdatedDate)
    from [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.MerchandisingArea 
    inner join [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.Project  on Project.ProjectID= MerchandisingArea.ProjectID
    ) as AreasUpdated,



    (Select 
    SUM ( case when MA.PublishStatus = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
    from [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.MerchandisingArea MA
    inner join [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.PublishingStatus  on PublishingStatus.PublishStatusId = MA.PublishStatus
    ) as SuccessPublished,



    (Select
    SUM ( case when MA.PublishStatus = 3 then 1 else 0 end) 
    from [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.MerchandisingArea MA
    inner join [ondemand.10cms.com].Project.PublishingStatus  on PublishingStatus.PublishStatusId= MA.PublishStatus
    ) as FailedPublished


    from  [ondemand.10cms.com].Company.Company  c
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @meewoK No error as such, however everything after suspended users brings back the same data for each column on each row

Comment: They are all counts with no where clauses, thats probably why they are similar?

Comment: @SelectDistinct Unfortunately I have also tried that and the same results come back

Comment: But the where clause is the same for each count? Althought you have different joins on some it is entirely possible that the data being returned is correct.

Comment: @SelectDistinct Yes each where clause collerates to each sub query and the reason why the data isn't correct is because each row with the same data is just the total of each in its table not, and not based upon each individual company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by adding another inner join to each sub query and also another where clause